# Having a callback method specify who gets notified?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, callback

I'm working on a C# application that sends messages across a server through a queue. What happens is that there are two different objects pushing stuff on the queue which are sent as messages that are deserialzed by the recievers. So my problem is that for each of those two pushers, there is a reciever. So whats happening is basically, the two recievers are waiting to be notified that a message has been recieved and they process it and whatnot. There are one of two things occuring:

1) As there's a single queue, as whatever manages the sending of messages across the Server alerts GeneralReciever (the class that both recievers as a subclass of) and the recievers attempt to grab the message and process. This is done through a callback function that is invoked, so both recievers are notified. I think what is occuring is that whoever happens to start processing the message first gets it, and if the message is for the wrong reciever, it just gets lost as it can't process it.

2)Both recievers are recieving every message, but the delay between how long it takes the recievers to process the object and the server sending the message to the recievers makes it so that some will not get processed.

I apologize that this isn't the most helpful description, but basically how my program works is:

pusher pushes a message object to server queue.
Server queue pops the message on other side, and invokes the messageRecived(message) callback for GeneralReiciever (which in turn activates the messageReicieved for both recievers. I was wondering if there's a way to only call say Reciever A, if the message is intended for reciever A, and same for B. This is all conceptual so I'm not expecting anyone to write me any code.

I'd appreciate any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add something to the messages themselves outside of the actual data that determines where it ends up. Think of it like ports on a computer. The network messages come with a portion that says what port it wants to end up in, and the computer/router/whatever puts it towards the program receiving on that port.

```
if(Message.StartsWith("A"))
{
   A.messageReceived(Message);
}
else if(Message.StartsWith("B")
{
   B.messageReceived(Message);
}
```

Of course, you would probably put in a byte at the start, not a string (depending on how your network stuff works)

Comment: I didnt make the server stuff, but from what I can tell, it's not aware of each individual receiver waiting for messages. It just invokes a callback method, so whatever object with that callback signature gets alerted. Every reciever is a subclass of GeneralReciever. (I think this is how callbacks work, correct me if I'm wrong). Would a possible solution be to say have 2 different onMessageRecieved() methods (say onMessageRecievedA and onMessageRecievedB), then I can see what the message will deserialize into before I invoke the callback.

Comment: If it deserializes to A, call the A one and same with B? This sounds pretty haxy, but could something like this work?

Comment: If you can't individually choose receivers, perhaps add the handling code to the receivers themselves. So in A you'd put an if(A) and in B you'd put an if(B) before all logic.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are looking for a publish/subscribe pattern where you also can target specific clients for every message.

There are many ways and frameworks to do this, but the one I know best is XSockets.NET.
In there you can target specific clients with lambda expressions, like this..

```
this.SendTo(p => p.SomeProperty == SomeCondition, objectToSend, "topic");
```

[QuickStart](http://xsockets.net/docs/quick-start)